# webapp2 session clearing not working on logout

Tags: google-app-engine

I've implemented user authentication using webapp2_extras and handlers are taken from here:

https://github.com/abahgat/webapp2-user-accounts/blob/master/main.py

Hosted on GAE, some changes I've made is I'm throwing back the response to Angular for rerouting.

As you can see in logout handler on the above link that has:
self.auth.unset_session()

I tried printing session var after that, its not cleared. So I tried self.session.clear(). That cleared the session - confirmed printing self.session and self.session_store.get_session()...prints {}.

Here's the query - when I refresh, user is still logged in. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`self.auth.set_session()` and `self.auth.unset_session()` are actually creating & deleting `UserToken` objects from datastore

Go here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query?ns=&kind=UserToken&sortDir=DESCENDING&sortCol=created

Login and watch a new object get created

Then Logout and see if it gets deleted

You also may want to confirm that your `LogOutHandler` is actually receiving a session/cookies. `print self.auth.get_session_data()`

`self.auth.set_session()` pops the value from that and then deletes it from the datastore, so if `print self.auth.get_session_data()` returns nothing, then `self.auth.set_session()` will assume there is nothing to delete

Comment: @Ekta was this answer useful for you?